# JWPlayer - Get all playlist ids

Tags: jwplayer

Is there any way to retrieve all **playlist ids** from an account?
Using JSON call.

I want this endpoint: /v2/playlists/

See the platform API:
https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/docs/delivery-api-reference/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull a list of your playlist ids you will want to use the Management API:
https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/methods/channels/videos/show.html